# Почему локальную переменную можно дважды объявить в разных ветках if...else но нельзя в switch...case?

Tags: javascript, условия

Пример 1:

```
var foo = false;

switch(foo) {

    case true:

        let a = 'Истина!';
        alert(a);   
    break;

    case false:

        let a = 'Ложь!';
        alert(a);
    break   
}

//Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

Пример 2:

```
var foo = false;

if (foo)  {
    let a = 'Истина!';
    alert(а);
}

else {
    let a = 'Ложь!';
    alert(a);
}

// Ложь!
```

Получается в switch...case компьютер проходит по всем ветвям и инициализирует переменные, но не выполняет остальной код? Почему так?

Answer (score 4):

Эта особенность пришла с с/с++, где case - это просто метки для виртуального goto (которым в данном случае является switch). А фигурные скобки после switch определяют блок. А внутри одного блока (без вложений) нельзя объявить одну переменную дважды.

В другие языки эту "особенность" скопировали.

В if/else как бы тоже не всегда можно просто так объявить переменную - нужно обязательно добавить фигурные скобки. К примеру, так нельзя (да, я понимаю, пример странноват, но это так задумано).

```
if (foo)  
    let a = 'x';
else
    let a = 'y';
```

Comment: Ага, т.е. если я уберу первый break, то при первом кейсе выполнится условие как для первого так и для второго, а при втором - только для второго, спасибо!

Comment: Логично же? и сразу стает понятно, что break - это ещё один goto :)

Comment: А фигурные скобки в javascript в целом служат для того, чтобы "собирать" множество строк кода в что-то единое к чему можно обратиться по адресу, верно? Для объекта, для функции, для switch и т.д.

Comment: фигурные скобки - это блок кода. А блок кода может работать как "одна строка" (то есть, как одно выражение), но только определяет свою область для переменных. Но это очень-очень грубо (на собеседованиях так лучше не отвечать).
Переформулирую - там, где можно написать одну строку кода (то есть, до точки с запятой) практически всегда можно написать много кода в фигурных скобках. А вот можно ли к этому обращаться "по адресу" - я тут даже не знаю, что имелось ввиду.

Answer (score 3):

Можно. Обратите внимание на фигурные скобочки.

```js
var foo = false;

switch (foo) {

  case true:
    {
      let a = 'Истина!';
      console.log(a);
    }
    break;

  case false:
    {
      let a = 'Ложь!';
      console.log(a);
    }
    break
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

> The let statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally
>   initializing it to a value.
>
> `let` объявляет переменную, видимую/существующую внутри блока ...

Comment: Как в этом случае меняется логика?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov Почему она должна меняться?

Comment: В моем примере возникает ошибка, а в Вашем - нет. Значит у вас компилятор действует по другому алгоритму, вот что я имею ввиду.

Answer (score 3):

Let видна только на уровне скобки. В случае if/else используют отдельные скобки, а в случае case вы не используете скобки. Если if/else напишете без скобок, то там тоже будет такая же ошибка.